# getting (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)) on trying to load a webpage through watir

Tags: firefox, selenium, watir, selenium-webdriver

getting (Make sure Firefox is installed or set the path manually with

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path= (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError))
```

on trying to  load a webpage through watir.

I have latest version of firefox installed.
I was trying to run

```
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
$browser.goto("www.google.com")
$browser.text_field(:id, "gbqfq").set("zipcar\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the path manually to [selenium-webdriver.rb](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings). It is located under the gems folder of the path to Ruby, which would be like this in Windows:

```
require 'selenium/webdriver'
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:\Users\default\Desktop\firefox'
```